# yii2 form AJAX to different action url

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I am not able to make it work:
also it is always redirecting to `action/create' whereas i want to not to redirect to that action.

my code is like this in footer view:

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#quick-contact").on('submit',function(event) {
//  $("#quick-contact").on('beforeSubmit',function(event) {


        event.preventDefault(); // stopping submitting
        console.log("step1");
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = form.serialize();
      //  var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        var url = $(this).attr('/quick-contact/create');

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData

        })

        .done(function(response) {
            if (response.data.success == true) {
                alert("Wow you commented");
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
      //  return false;
    });
}); 
    </script>
<?php //pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>
<div id="contact-form">    

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action'=>'/quick-contact/create','id'=>'quick-contact','method'=>'post']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textarea(['rows' => 2]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>


    <div id="quick-contact-form">
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
     <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
     <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Saved!</h4>
     <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

// display error message
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')): ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
     <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
     <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Saved!</h4>
     <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
            </div></div>
            <?php // pjax::end(); ?>
```

and in controller action like:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new QuickContact();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            var_dump($_POST);
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->requset->post()) && $model->save()) {            

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Thanks We will get in touch with you');

            // $st = Yii::$app->getTable;
              //      $email_template = $st->email_template(1);
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setTo('info@mywebsolutions.co.in')
                ->setFrom(['info@mywebsolutions.co.in'])
                ->setSubject('QuickContact')
                ->setHtmlBody('Request from - '.$model->name.'<br>'.'Email - '.$model->email. '<br>'.'Message - '.$model->message) 
                ->send();

                      /*  Yii::$app->mailer->compose('template', ['id' => 1, 'email_template' => $email_template,   'sender_name'=>$model->name,'message'=>$model->address])

                ->setTo($this->email)
                ->setFrom([$email => "vedic"])
                ->setSubject($this->subject)
                //->setHtmlBody('Hi '.$this->name.'<br>'.'Welcome to Nexgen'.'<br>'.'We confirm of having received your Enquiry/feedback as below'.'<br>'.$this->body )
                ->send();
                                */
            }else{
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','There was an error in submission.');
            }
            //return $this->render('/site/index');

            }

           // return $this->renderPartial('/site/index');

    }
```

**updated jquery script code:**

Now ajax request is going through, but the response I am getting is like:

`name   Unknown Property
message Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::requset
code    0
type    yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
file    /var/www/clients/client2/web238/web/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php`

Comment: you need to use `$("#quick-contact").on(''beforeSubmit")` instead of `$("#quick-contact").submit()`

Comment: Hi Omer - should I replace -` $("#quick-contact").submit(function(event) {` with `$("#quick-contact").on(''beforeSubmit") {`

Comment: yes you should swap them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace the

```
$("#quick-contact").submit(function(event) {
```

with

```
$("#quick-contact").on('beforeSubmit',function(event) {
```

**Update**

The reason you are getting the error is because you have several errors in your console regarding the 3rd party scripts, and until unless you remove them you wont be able to get it working, you need to fix the following

[image]

Another thing that is missing is the `return false;` statement in your `beforeSubmit` event you should add this line after the ajax call, to prevent form submission.

```
$("#quick-contact").on('beforeSubmit',function(event) {

    //....your code for ajax call

    return false;
});
```

**Update 2**

The reason for the error is the spelling for the `requset` which should be rather `request` you need to change the line

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->requset->post()) && $model->save()) {
```

to

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
```

if you still into problems please add a separate question as this question addresses the ajax part only which is solved already.

Comment: Hi Omer, I think still there is something else is missing as well as I am not getting any alert in console as well as i added a `var_dump($_POST);` without any result.

Comment: I am getting this warning -  in console:jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function @https://ips.mywebsolutions.co.in/:1941:26
mightThrow@https://ips.mywebsolutions.co.in/assets/8c32e08f/jquery.js:3583:29
resolve/</process<@https://ips.mywebsolutions.co.in/assets/8c32e08f/jquery.js:3651:12
 undefined and error - typeError: jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function. is it possible that this is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Omer - not sure where exactly I should add `return false`, should ` event.preventDefault(); // stopping submitting` not do what you say. also I tried changing the code from (beforeSubmit)` to just `(submit)` and I can see that the ajax request and console log appearing. but after that I am getting the error - In the console I can see the request parameter as - _`csrf ysXwX54exTRZng1WA8eHy-e3Wk9r-vkdXZQi2bcVbR-MgqUJ31OdXmnJWAJoiPCMiY4WDV3Cl04QwVK4znJcKQ==
QuickContact[name] pawan
QuickContact[email] pkjoshi.sbp@gmail.com
QuickContact[message] Testing+2.27`

Comment: @Joshi , i have updated the answer but you need to fix the other errors first in order to get the ajax working

Comment: Hi Omer - I have eliminated all the other script error showing in console. but somehow the ajax request is not firing with `beforeSubmit`, but I have revised the code, where ajax request is made correctly, but I am not getting correct response from controller.

Comment: Thanks Omer - Such a silly mistake, you pointed it out correctly.

Comment: it happens with all of us all the time @Joshi